# Add individual in owl file with Jena

Tags: jena, owl

I have an OWL file named Modelling.owl which created using Protege 4.2. But then I have to modify it by registering some new Individual and it's properties using Jena.
For example I have Class Model, I have to add Individual for this class. Anyone know how, and it would be nice if you can give some sample code. I tried to look for tutorial but unfortunately I didn't find the comprehensive one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JENA Tutorial - http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html

```
// create the reasoning model using the base
OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, base );

// create a dummy paper for this example
OntClass paper = base.getOntClass( NS + "Paper" );
Individual p1 = base.createIndividual( NS + "paper1", paper );
```

This is an excerpt from a larger explanation (about half way through).